# macOs Sierra arabesque screensaver crash in preview and can't be set

Tags: macos, crash, screensaver

I have a Macbook Air 11.6" (early 2015) with macOS 10.12.6 installed on my Mac, and I noticed that the arabesque screensaver is not functioning properly. It crashed when previewing the screensaver in System Preferences, and it changed to another screensaver when it was selected. I have tried to reboot the machine on [safe mode](https://support.apple.com/zh-hk/HT201262) and also reset the [NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063).

Here is my question. Is there anyone also facing this issue (this issue somehow existed since 10.12.3), and is there any solution to that?

Comment: My iMac 2015 4K was updated from 10.11.6 to 10.12.5 and I have the same problem with Arabesque. I can say that its suffix has changed from 'qtz' to 'saver'. Arabesque is a Quartz screen saver and this is the problem, I think.

Comment: Hi @user248708, thanks for the response :). I have tried to change that from .saver to .qtz but no anvil... any suggestion?

Comment: this is old but if it helps, my 2015 retina macbook also has trouble with this screen saver. all the others are fine